# Will Memory Tagging Extension be implemented in x86?

Tags: x86, cpu-architecture, hardening

Memory Tagging Extension is a promissing memory protection feature.
Does any one know if it is planed to be ported to x86?

For those who don't know it: 
  1) https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/arm/mte
  2) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lLEcbXidK2o

Comment: Can you link to something about it for the benefit of people who haven't heard of it?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://lwn.net/Articles/643797/

Comment: Memory protection keys is another security mechanism...

Comment: Seems off-topic to me.

Answer (score 1):

Intel did announce that they will eventually add memory tagging in the [Intel Architecture Day 2020](https://d1io3yog0oux5.cloudfront.net/_6f1902c731ed10bd8538c1c8c9ca7ca1/intel/db/861/8422/pdf/Intel-Architecture-Day-2020-Presentation-Slides.pdf) presentation. However, no timeline was given.